# Inrush current handling for relays

Tags: circuit-design, relay, led-driver, inrush-current

I am building a controller (ESP based) to sit in front of a Meanwell LED Driver ([HLG-150H-12B](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/HLG-150H/HLG-150H-spec.pdf)).

I intend on using a trigger relay module to switch the 230VAC-Live into the HLG, however I am slightly concerned about inrush current. The HLG spec sheet lists 65A of inrush (but 0.75A of continuous @ 230VAC), but my trigger relay is only rated for 10A (continuous)....

Should I be looking for a particular relay that specifies max load to handle the inrush? Or is there a more appropriate solution?

Comment: Why do you want to switch it on the high-voltage mains side? You can just use a transistor to switch the isolated low-voltage side. That's much cheaper and much more reliable. A simple N-FET will do the trick.

Comment: Well, HLG's DC 65A inrush is on the CCS LED side, On the AC mains side, the AC current is very small, so any cheapy 5V (use High tirg for 3V3 ESP) will do.

Comment: You can use an [NTC thermistor](https://product.tdk.com/en/techlibrary/applicationnote/howto_ntc-limiter.html) to limit the inrush current.

Comment: @JonathanS. Good question, the HLG datasheet says switching the whole driver off on the mains side is how to achieve a true 0% output... switching the low-voltage side would certainly be easier & :safer", but for a Light, which spends 70% of its time "off", then it makes more sense to complete kill the power to the driver entirely?

Comment: @tlfong01 spec sheet says 65AMP @ 230vac, so its definitely inrush to the driver, rather than inrush to the LED's...

Comment: @tephra: Let me see.  (1) 230VAC * 65A ~= 15 kW!  (2) But the datasheet and product sheet don't say so.  (3) Ref: (a) 150W Constant Voltage + Constant Current LED Driver HLG-150H series - Meanwell
https://www.meanwell.com/Upload/PDF/HLG-150H/HLG-150H-SPEC.PDF

(b) 709-HLG150H-12B HLG-150H-12B MEAN WELL LED Power Supply 150W 12V 12.5A 90-305VAC IP67 Rated - Mouser
https://www.mouser.hk/ProductDetail/MEAN-WELL/HLG-150H-12B?qs=3IPTn0w%2F0t8oh6LhXHSYEA%3D%3D

Comment: @tlfong01: yes, thats the datasheet I am looking at, specifically: "INRUSH CURRENT (Typ.) = COLD START 65A(t =425 us measured at 50% I ) at 230VAC;width peak Per NEMA 410"

so, yes its 15kw, but only for 425 microseconds...

i guess thats my question, do i just ignore that when spec'ing a relay? :)

Comment: @tephra: My apologies. I did not read your question too carefully. I need to think hard and see if I can give any answer. Cheers.

Comment: The spec in the datasheet is no doubt worst-case, then the AC sine wave is at it's peak. Solution: use a solid state relay with zero-crossing detection built-in; there won't be anywhere near that much inrush as it has to ride the AC wave from zero.

Comment: What is a ‘trigger relay module’? Have you read the datasheet for the relay?

Comment: @dandavis - thankyou, do you have a suggested part number? this sort of thing (from a noobs perspective) is a bit of a minefield, so a starting point is helpful :)

Comment: @Kartman, as in an Arduino trigger relay module, the relay onboard is srd-05vdc-sl-c; which only lists a maximum continuous load rating (10amp)

Comment: @tephra: I also read the installation manual, but could not find any hint to handle the in rush current. 
MeanWell LED Power Supply Installation Manual - MeanWell
https://www.meanwellusa.com/Upload/PDF/LED_EN.pdf

Comment: @tlfong01 thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 4):

> Should I be looking for a particular relay that specifies max load to handle the inrush? Or is there a more appropriate solution?

You would need to select a relay, from 'high-inrush current' models, considering the TV rating mentioned in the data sheet.

The TV rating, as per UL and CSA standards, is an assessment of the inrush current withstanding capability of relay contacts as follows:

TV3 - 51A, TV4 - 65A, TV5 - 78A and TV8 - 117A, TV10 - 141A, TV15 - 191A.

With the power supply inrush current being 65A, TV4 or TV5 would be the right choice for your application.

Comment: thanks, it appears that the relay i'm using at the moment (or had planned to) doesn't have a TV rating, so i'm going to go find one that does...

Answer (score 1):

Do it the easy way, use a zero crossing solid state AC switch. They are available for a few dollars to a lot depending on brand and other options. They are available designed for 10 amps 230V and larger. They come agency rated for your country, give you the isolation needed between mains and control. There are many brands available. Many look like this one.

[image]
Picture from opto22 web site.

Comment: thanks for this, correct me if I am wrong, but the zero-crossing bit seems to have the desired affect, by not allowing the load circuit to "engage" at the the peak supply current...   

pretty cool, i always thought that you get 230vac straight away, but obviously when your looking at the waveform in microsecond time there is going to be a time when the current = 0... (right?)   

so if you align the load turn on time with that you naturally restrict the inrush - is that about right?

Comment: You got it, also it turns off at about zero cross (when the current drops below the semiconductor holding current). eliminating that problem as well.

Comment: Did you see this doc from TE? https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=13C3206_AppNote&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN

Comment: my post didn't finish - i meant to say thats for inductive loads (ie zero crossing SSR is not recommended); but im assuming the HLG, being a switched mode power supply is more capacative load?